# Interaction between JQuery validation and form submit handler: Broken, or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Some of my forms require validation, for which I use the JQuery validation plug-in.

Some of my forms require a custom submit handler (which conditionally pops-up a confirmation dialog before submitting, independent of validation).  I attach the handler to the form like so:

```
function confirmHandlerAttach(form, handler) {
  $(form).off("submit", confirmHandlerDefault);
  $(form).on("submit", handler);
}
```

Both validation and the submit handler are attached at doc ready based on classes.  Independently, both work fine.  The problem is that it seems that the form's submit handler being called regardless of whether the validation succeeds.  See a simplfied example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sferrari63/VGj2R/).

This isn't what I would expect.  I would think that validation would prevent both the submission and the submit handler from running.  Am I doing something wrong, or are my expectations wrong?

I realize that I could instead use validation's submitHandler property, and if necessary I'll go that route.  But since validation and confirmation (or any other submit handler) are really independent functions, it seems a shame to have to change all form submit handlers to deal with the JQuery validate plug-in just in case some form uses validation.

Comment: It all depends on what order the event handlers were added, and how you are preventing the default action. Keep in mind, preventing the default action ***does not*** prevent additional handlers from happening.

Comment: Your jsFiddle perfectly demonstrates why you should use the plugin's `submitHandler` callback function rather than an external submit handler.

Comment: To ensure that your custom submit handler code only fires when the form is valid, you could test it using `.valid()`:  http://jsfiddle.net/VGj2R/1/ ~ Although I think this is totally redundant when it's precisely what the plugin's `submitHandler` was made for.

Comment: I don't think the order of adding handlers applies to this question: I'm adding only the form submit handler, which I would guess is on a different "handler queue" than any handlers JQuery validate adds.

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, newbie submitted the comment before it was completed and exceeded the 5 min limit for editing.  Meant to continue:  However, the fact that preventing the default action prevents only the form submission, not the on-submit handler, is probably the key thing I was missing.  I figured that if the submit is prevented, so is the submit handler, but it seems not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    // your rules,
    submitHandler: function (form) { 
        alert('valid form submitted');
        return false;
    }
});

$("#myform").on('submit', function() {
    alert("Real submit handler");
});
```

Your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sferrari63/VGj2R/

Your `submit` handler is firing every time the submit button is clicked even when the form is "invalid".

**Quote OP**:

> This isn't what I would expect. I would think that validation would
>   prevent both the submission and the submit handler from running. **Am I
>   doing something wrong, or are my expectations wrong?**

You're doing something unnecessary and your expectations are wrong.  Just because the jQuery Validate plugin is preventing the default submit action, does not mean that any external submit handlers will not fire.

This is the reason the developer gives you the `submitHandler` and `invalidHandler` callback functions.  Since the plugin blocks default submit automatically, these callbacks replace the need for you to create `submit` handler(s) of your own.

- `submitHandler` fires on click of the submit button only if/when the form is "valid".
- `invalidHandler` fires on click of the submit button only if/when the form is "invalid".

(Note:  if your submit button contains `class="cancel"`, the form will always evaluate as "valid" and the `submitHandler` will always fire... all rules will be ignored.  ***EDIT***:  `class="cancel"` has since been deprecated in favor of the `formnovalidate="formnovalidate"` attribute.)

If, for some odd reason, you need this additional `submit` handler, you can test the form using the `.valid()` method.  Although, I don't recommend doing this when you already have perfectly good `submit` handlers built into the plugin.

```
$("#myform").on('submit', function() {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        alert("Form is valid");
    }
});
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/VGj2R/1/

Since the plugin is handling the `submit` event, it would be more correct to fire this code below on the button's `click` handler instead.

```
$("#mySubmitButton").on('click', function() {
    if ($("#myform").valid()) {
        alert("Form is valid");
    }
});
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/VGj2R/2/

However, unless your form does not have a submit button, the code above is unnecessary where the `submitHandler` callback function can be used instead.

Comment: The reason I'm so reluctant to use validation's submit handler is that I want the confirmation "plug-in" that I'm writing to not rely on validation plug-in being there.  If I use validation's submit handler I need to either require that validation is done on all forms that use confirmation, or detect whether validation is being done and attach to its submit handler if it is, or to the form's submit handler if it isn't.  As I said in my question, I can do this, but I don't think it's clean.

Comment: "Just because the jQuery Validate plugin is preventing the default submit action, does not mean that any external submit handlers will not fire."

Thanks. I've been thinking of submission as "call the submit handlers, and if they don't prevent it submit the form".  I figured if JQuery validate prevents submission it would prevent both of these, but now I understand that this is not how it works.

But the "valid()" method that you and Kevin B point out lets me do what I want, if my handler considers the form valid if .valid() is true OR if the form has no valid() method.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3044637, KevinB never mentioned the `.valid()` method anywhere, but I'm glad it worked out for you.

Comment: 1+ for this. Its really help me.